# Why is the <a> element inside <nav> losing a couple of pixels in the width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a responsive menu for a website, but I have a problem: The **a tag (red color)** is losing a couple of pixels when defining the 100% width of the **div (blue color)**.

To notice the difference it is necessary to open the link of the Pen, use the Chrome inspector and select the red box. The width is shown with pixels less than 30 (example: 28.72, 27.60, etc.).

I have tried other HTML tags although the result has been the same. Why does it happen and what would be the optimal solution for the  tag to keep the width and height at 30px, please?

Here the pen: https://codepen.io/Jnico/pen/RQaEoa

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu__container {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  height: 55px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu__buttons {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.button {
  padding: 6px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu__container">
  <div class="menu">
    <a class="logo"></a>
    <div class="menu__buttons">
      <a class="button">Button 1</a>
      <a class="button">Button 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I found the solution: min-width: 30px. If I can help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best alternative was:

```
.logo {
    min-width: 30px
}
```

Because "min" can be used without interrupting my receptive system with fixed pixels or by adding extensive code.

Answer (score 1):

Because of flexbox..

Add flex: 0 0 auto to your .logo so it doesn't flex at all an it should be fine ;) Also, you don't need display:inline-block there, as it's a flex-item already.

```
  .logo {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    flex:0 0 auto;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I found a solution: .logo { min-width: 30px } It's ok too?

Comment: @JuanNicolás sure, min-width will do. But "flex:0 0 30px;" and no width declaration at all might be the most "correct" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When i set **display** to **inline-table** or **table** is ok and set 30*30

or you can set **flex** to `0 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use `flex-wrap: wrap` to the flex container if you want that the flexible items will wrap if necessary.

Or you have to use `flex-basis:30px` to the `<a>`(No need to mention the `width`) and

`flex-grow:1` to the `.menu__buttons` so that it can take the remaining width...

And remove `width:100%` from the `.menu__buttons`...No need

[**Updated Code**](https://codepen.io/bhuwanb9/pen/zRqymg)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I found a solution: .logo { min-width: 30px } It's ok too?

Comment: @JuanNicolás Glad you found a solution...you can use `flex-basis:30px` instead of width too...